# Why prepared statement breaks natural join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a **natural join query** that worked fine until I learned that prepared statements are much safer and it broke my query. I did some research and read that prepared statements and natural joins don't play well together. Here is my original query:

```
$query = "select * from table1 natural join table2 where table1.id='$id' ";
```

I need to do a join on query but need 2 columns to match in both tables, state and city.
How can I achieve this and select all columns from both tables?
This is what I have so far but not working:

```
$query = "select * from table1 join table2 on table1.state = table2.state and table1.city = table2.city where table1.id='$id'";
```

Right now I'm just trying to get the query to work using JOIN ON and then I want to replace table1.id='$id' with table.id=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `table1.id = '$id'` you use `table1.id = ?` just like you said.

Then you run `->execute()`:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query) or die($db->error);
$stmt->execute(array(123));
```

Comment: doesn't work. That's what I had but it only gives me the columns from table1. But if I use my old code: `$result = $db->query($query);
 $num_results = $result->num_rows; $row = $result->fetch_assoc();` Everything works fine.

Comment: I think I was mixing OOP with procedural; changed it to this `$result = $db->prepare($query);
 $result->bind_result();
 $result->fetch($id);` But still only gives me table1 results

Comment: @whatdafrak do the columns of table1 and table2 have the same name? :)

Comment: Two of the columns are same. 'State' and 'City'. When I do natural join before prepared statement, it finds the match.

Comment: @whatdafrak If you copy/paste your query into the mysql client app and replace the `?` with an id, you should get the same results.

Comment: @whatdafrak that makes no sense; maybe you should post more code, before and after would be best.

Comment: Not much left that could be problem. I have this for connection:   `@ $db = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database );`  and this displays results:  `$row->fetch();  
    $name = $row['name'];  
    $address = $row['address'];  
    $city = $row['city'];  
    $state = $row['state'];`   Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I just found I have fallback subquery that queries table1 if the natural join fails. So my guess is the prepared statement query is failing and if it outputs 0 rows, my subquery kicks in. So this whole time it's the prepared statement causing the problem and I must have something wrong. Thanks for your help. I'll try to understand prepared statements better and try to get that part to work and natural join query should as well

Comment: @whatdafrak to help debug you can add: `$db->prepare($query) or die($db->error);`

Comment: I got it!! Here is my final code:  
 `$query = "select * from table1 natural join table2 where table1_id=? ";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query) or die($db->error);
 $stmt->bind_param(i,$id);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  $name = $row['name'];`